# Unable to scroll down in eBay using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the testing of eBay.com

(https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Cricket&_sacat=888&_udlo=3536),

In the process, I searched Cricket on the Search bar and selected "Sporting Goods" in the search category.
Upon Landing in a new page

I want to click on a Cricket bat which has the title "adidas Pellara Elite XT Grade 1 Cricket Bat", however, am unable to do so

I have already tried using JS executor to scroll down to the concerned Item, but that did not work

```
public void search() {
  WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gh-ac\"]"));

  WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gh-cat\"]"));

  searchBox.sendKeys("Cricket");
  Select category1 = new Select (category);
  category1.selectByVisibleText("Sporting Goods");
  searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   

  WebElement Save_Search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"w9-follow-follow-faux-btn\"]"));

  Save_Search.click();
  WebElement Price_Filter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"srp-river-results-query_answer1-w0-x-carousel-items\"]/ul/li[3]/div/a/div"));

  Price_Filter.click();
  WebElement Adidas_Pellara_Bat = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("adidas Pellara Elite XT Grade 1"));

  js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView", Adidas_Pellara_Bat);

  Adidas_Pellara_Bat.click();

 }
```

If I use JS Executor to scroll down, I am getting `Null Pointer Exception`, otherwise, I am simply getting `No Such Element Exception` or a pre-defined message from the website saying they dont have this product

Comment: When others will search they may not get `adidas Pellara Elite XT Grade 1 Cricket Bat` listed as a search result.

Comment: Not Sure what you meant Sir, if I search using the term "adidas Pellara Elite XT Grade 1 Cricket Bat", the item is still there

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find it :(

Comment: You are right Sir, while the heading for the item is still there, if I click on the heading, it says the item is missing.

Comment: As for the actual problem, I found a workaround

Comment: Instead of using By.xpath or Csspath, it performs better if we use By.Link text or partiallinktext

Comment: Thanks for your time Sir